# Array with enumerated elements

Tags: java, array

Java program uses the following construction: (provided mainly for context)

```
public class Utils {
  public static final byte PROVIDER_FOO = 0;
  public static final byte PROVIDER_MOO = 1;
  public static final byte PROVIDER_BAR = 2;
  public static final byte PROVIDER_FUR = 3;
  public static final byte PROVIDER_BOO = 4;
  public static final byte PROVIDER_ANOTHER_FOO = 5;
  public static final byte PROVIDER_YET_ANOTHER = 6;

  public static String [] PROVIDERS = {"FOO", "MOO", "BAR", "FUR", "BOO",
    "PROVIDER_ANOTHER_FOO", "PROVIDER_YET_ANOTHER"};

  ...

}
```

So, each element of array has a number. And each array index in range `0..6` has text representation. Text representation is using in outer world: reading configs, printing results. Number representation is using in internal tasks. So, there a problem to transform text representation to number and vice versa. Number is transferring to string as following:

```
// someObject.getProviderNumeric() returns numeric value for someObj's provider
String strProvider = Utils.PROVIDERS[someObj.getProviderNumeric()]
```

String is transferring to number like this:

```
int getNumericByText(String strProvider) {
  for (int i = 0; i < Utils.PROVIDER_YET_ANOTHER; ++i) {
    if (strProvider.equals(Utils.PROVIDERS[i])) {
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

It looks pretty bulky. What is the best way to rewrite?

Comment: I am on the fence with this question. It looks very much like example code, which I think/hope you have heard before that we don't like here. Unlike Stack Overflow, we prefer to look at real code instead of example code. That said, I feel that most of your example code is only provided as context for your problem, which is why I currently have not voted to close.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - Thank you for your answer (+1). Actually the code in my questions is pretty coincide to the code in production. It was just renaming and some reduction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, what you need is an `enum`.

Use an enum and I believe what you are looking for will be provided for you.

```
public enum Utils {
    PROVIDER_FOO, PROVIDER_MOO, PROVIDER_BAR, PROVIDER_FUR,
    PROVIDER_BOO, PROVIDER_ANOTHER_FOO, PROVIDER_YET_ANOTHER;
}
```

String to int:

```
Utils.valueOf(str).ordinal();
```

int to String:

```
Utils.values()[intValue].name();
```

Or if you want to be a bit more advanced, I suggest reading [this answer of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45337/31562)

Comment: Thank you! `Utils.values[intValue].name();` doesn't work for me. Did you mean `Utils.values()[intValue].name();`?

Comment: @Loom yes, exactly!

Answer (score 4):

The obvious solution is to use an `enum` with custom fields for the numeric value and the custom string representation, and a static map to cache the mapping of string values to the enumerated values. Something like this:

```
enum Provider {
    FOO(0, "Foo"),
    MOO(1, " Moo"),
    BAR(2, "Bar");

    private final byte value;
    private final String label;

    private static final Map<String, Provider> map;
    static {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Provider provider : Provider.values()) {
            map.put(provider.label, provider);
        }
    }

    private Provider(byte value, String label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
    }

    public static Provider fromString(String label) {
        return map.get(label);
    }
}
```