# Enum vs lookup table for temporary and permanent teeth

Tags: java, enum

I'm implementing a solution in Java using Ebean and I'm having some issues choosing between using `enum`s or simply look up tables.

I have a table "Tooth". A tooth can be "Temporary" or "Permanent".

I could create a simple `enum`:

```
@EnumMapping(nameValuePairs = "TEMPORARY=T, PERMANENT=P")
public enum DentitionType { TEMPORARY, PERMANENT; }
```

However, if I want to do a direct SQL query, I have to convert "T" and "P", so a solution would be to use a lookup table as below:

```
@Entity
public class DentitionType {

   @Column(length = 15)
   public String name;

    private static DentitionType permanent;

    public boolean isTemporary() {
        return !this.equals(getPermanent());
    }

    public boolean isPermanent() {
        return this.equals(getPermanent());
    }

    public static DentitionType getPermanent() {
        if (permanent == null) {
            permanent = DentitionType.FIND.byId(2L);
        }

        return permanent;
    }
}
```

This feels kind of hardcoded and for larger tables a lot of `isSomething` functions are required.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Not sure what is asked for. Do you want a better version of the enum to have defined enumValue pairs instead of the annotation?

Comment: I would like to have the best of both worlds: have an entity (stored as a table in the db) but with values which have specific meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend making an enum with properties, such as:

```
public enum DentitionType {
    TEMPORARY(1), PERMANENT(2);

    private final int id;
    private DetentionType(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public static DententionType forId(int id) {
        for (DententionType dentention : DetentionType.values()) {
            if (dentention.getId() == id) {
                return dentention;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is an easy way of mapping your enum to an int (you can also use a 'char' or 'String' or whatever you feel like). Then you can inside your `@Entity` class use some [JPA events](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event) to transform to/from enum and int.

Another solution is of course to simply use the [`@Enumerated` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569053/mapping-enum-types-with-hibernate-annotations) and automatically use the ordinal of the enum. Be aware however that there has been incidents where [someone accidentally switched the order of the enums, which caused DIAMONDS to become black](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36916/weekend-challenge-poker-hand-evaluation#comment60836_36936).

Answer (score 2):

With Enum you get these weapons for lookup:
 - DentitionType.TEMPORARY.getValue() to get the string "T" or "P".
 - DentitionType.valueOf("T") to get the enumType i.e DentitionType.TEMPORARY
 - For any new Type just add the type and your job is done.

```
public class DentitionType{
    TEMPORARY("T"),
    PERMANENT("P"),
    ARTIFICIAL("A"),
    ;

    private String value;
    private DentitionType( String value ){
        this.value = value;
    }
    public getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Considering the current program, instead of having multiple isXYZ, try

```
boolean isMatchingType(DentitionType type){ // For permanent use DentitionType.PERMANENT
    return this.name.equals(type.getValue());
}
```

Comment: As it is an `enum`, I would just compare them with `this == other`, using `.equals` for enums is not necessary.

Comment: But `enum`s are not persisted to their own table in the database.